# Change application media keys are refering to

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, media

I have multiple applications opened at the same time that are registered as playing media on Ubuntu in Gnome. In my case both Spotify and a YouTube tab in Firefox are opened.

When I use the media keys on my keyboard it is more or less decided randomly(?) whether Spotify pauses or YouTube starts.

How can I control what application the media keys will refer to?

[Two applications with media integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQe7M.png) (Since I am not yet allowed to post pictures, this is a link to a picture)

Comment: no idea, but you can try to disable media keys in firefox by going to "about:config" and setting media.hardwaremediakeys.enabled to false - there's also a preference "dom.media.mediasession.enabled" you can also set to false : https://www.ghacks.net/2020/03/23/firefox-will-soon-support-hardware-media-controls/

Comment: @Koen Thanks for the idea but I want to have them kept enabled. It is quite handy for me to pause/play Firefox and I was pretty happy as this feature got released.

Comment: Hi @Trojaner_ , have you found a solution to your problem?

Comment: @Pentaquark Kinda. I switched to KDE Plasma quite a while ago where you can actually select what application your media keys are referring to in a drop-down menu. For Gnome, I haven't found a solution however

Comment: @Trojaner_ thanks for your reply. I find it really odd that this is not possible in Gnome, and that this is not discussed more. To me this seems like a pretty big oversight...